# Swift: Cast class or protocol by name

Tags: swift

I try cast class by name to may class or protocol, but I always have nil as a result. For example, my easy test also return nil.

```
> po NSClassFromString("UITableViewCell")
▿ Optional<AnyObject.Type>
  - some : UITableViewCell

> po NSClassFromString("UITableViewCell") as? UIView
nil
```

why? what I do wrong? how I can cast it?

Comment: Because you're trying to cast a *type* to an *instance* of that type. Try using `UIView.Type` instead.

Comment: thanks, yes you right! my stupid fail